# Enterprise (in-house) Swift application quits on launch on iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, in-house-distribution

We find that our Swift application signed by in house certificate cannot run on iOS9 while it works correctly on iOS8. We have trusted the developer on settings -> general -> profiles, but when we try to launch the app, it gets stuck on the launch screen and then quits.

We don't have any clue from the logs. It only tells that it failed to launch after 20.00s.

I suspect that is an issue related to the signing. Because when I sign the application with an AdHoc certificate, it has no problem in running on iOS9.

Doesn't anybody know what is going on ?

---

Seems to related to these issues

- [Ad-Hoc distributed application failed to launch in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236809/ad-hoc-distributed-application-failed-to-launch-in-time)
- https://devforums.apple.com/thread/266111

---

```
**Device Logs**

Incident Identifier: B4564227-5CC9-447B-9A52-BEC5EB36EE44
CrashReporter Key:   9ec38d809cfa493300f95e440530ad11ac05e5d7
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Process:             xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx [2345]
Path:                /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/02F4CDFC-83E8-4474-9314-4848354A8FC0/xxxxxxx xxxxxxx.app/xxxxxx xxxxxxx
Identifier:          com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx
Version:             5097 (4.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-23 10:19:41.41 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-09-23 10:19:16.16 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A344)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.xxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxx failed to launch after 20.00s (launchIntent: foreground-interactive)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 22.260 (user 22.260, system 0.000), 56% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.002, 0% CPU

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0:
0   dyld                            0x0000000120054490 __fcntl + 8
1   dyld                            0x0000000120053e94 fcntl + 128
2   dyld                            0x0000000120042cec ImageLoaderMachO::loadCodeSignature(linkedit_data_command const*, int, unsigned long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 68
3   dyld                            0x0000000120045dd0 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 228
4   dyld                            0x0000000120041ccc ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 268
5   dyld                            0x0000000120033800 dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 396
6   dyld                            0x0000000120037d6c dyld::loadPhase5stat(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, stat*, int*, bool*, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 172
7   dyld                            0x0000000120037c38 dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 736
8   dyld                            0x0000000120037928 dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 192
9   dyld                            0x00000001200373e0 dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 696
10  dyld                            0x0000000120036edc dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 160
11  dyld                            0x0000000120033314 dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 236
12  dyld                            0x0000000120032fdc dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 160
13  dyld                            0x0000000120037ecc dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*) + 52
14  dyld                            0x000000012003fd34 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 332
15  dyld                            0x000000012003f1d8 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 124
16  dyld                            0x0000000120034c44 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 176
17  dyld                            0x0000000120035b64 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2408
18  dyld                            0x0000000120031044 _dyld_start + 68
```

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:

```
0x1000d8000 - 0x100543fff xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx arm64  <411a29d1e9843b17802cda346d9d7d5f> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/02F4CDFC-83E8-4474-9314-4848354A8FC0/xxxxxx xxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
0x100750000 - 0x100963fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <1c8fc0a4195f3207ac97389aafa69c65> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/02F4CDFC-83E8-4474-9314-4848354A8FC0/xxxxx xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x1014d0000 - 0x1014d7fff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64  <b751a5bac05c3293aa1c6b01d78d6bf7> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/02F4CDFC-83E8-4474-9314-4848354A8FC0/xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
0x120030000 - 0x12005bfff dyld arm64  <1b945967d665331dbf2600249e46660a> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Those are the live logs when we launch the app

```
Sep 24 10:23:22 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:25 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:26 iPad amfid[1091] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[1186] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/02AF80DC-26F3-4AAE-AD90-A4F148E574AE (sandbox)
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad amfid[1091] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:39 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 24 10:23:52 iPad syncdefaultsd[1127] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x15d50e780>
Sep 24 10:23:53 iPad amfid[1091] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:58 iPad amfid[1091] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of <FBApplicationProcess: 0x128ef74e0; Schneider Elect; pid: 1186> (reason: 1, description: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx failed to launch after 20.00s (launchIntent: foreground-interactive))
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: int _validateCodeDirectoryHashInDaemon(const char *, off_t, uint8_t *, int, int *): verify_code_directory returned 0x10004005
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx[0x9388][1186]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad ReportCrash[1187] <Warning>: saved type '109_Schneider Electric' report (2 of max 25) as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Schneider Electric_2015-09-24-102359_iPad.ips
Sep 24 10:23:59 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx[0x9388]' exited abnormally via signal.
Sep 24 10:24:00 iPad searchd[156] <Warning>: ====^^^^ DuetExpert missing requested data, people:0 applicationDeepLinks:1 applications:0 requests:36 missingAllDataRequests:0
Sep 24 10:24:04 iPad amfid[1091] <Error>: mig_source_handler: dispatch_mig_server returned 268435459
```

When we install the app from HockeyApp we have the following logs

```
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [Download]: Adding download(s): -7184518095014445338
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e0a5530> com.xxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxx <(null) *Not found in database*>
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-xxxxxxxxxx.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 103)
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Version=5106, ShortVersion=(null)>
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/28FBA6E7-DCD8-49B2-BA05-EFD951531A64
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6631F035-AF52-41CB-8299-7E781971C65E
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.00s; Overall: 0.09s
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e0b0aa0> com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6631F035-AF52-41CB-8299-7E781971C65E/-7184518095014445338.app> withPhase:3
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x14ce3cb20> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad ondemandd[180] <Error>: Application with ID: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx was installed, but it doesn't appear to have a bundle URL, we are taking no action on this.
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [Download]: Starting task: 7 with priority: 300 for download: -xxxxxxxxxxxxx bundleIdentifier: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx in session: com.apple.itunesstored.default
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e030650> com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6631F035-AF52-41CB-8299-7E781971C65E/-7184518095014445338.app> with icons
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-7184518095014445338.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 103)
Sep 24 10:26:03 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Version=5106, ShortVersion=(null)>
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9D5532A1-DAA6-432D-9F94-7A238714CC81
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E91022C-B4DB-42E2-9BC5-50683613AA1E
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.01s; Overall: 0.16s
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad ondemandd[180] <Error>: Application with ID: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx was installed, but it doesn't appear to have a bundle URL, we are taking no action on this.
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e04c7f0> com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E91022C-B4DB-42E2-9BC5-50683613AA1E/-7184518095014445338.app> withPhase:0
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x14dd52860> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
Sep 24 10:26:04 iPad lockdownd[66] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
Sep 24 10:26:08 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleARMPMUCharger: limiting USB input current to 1600 mA (measured 1164 mA)
Sep 24 10:26:08 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleARMPMUCharger: limiting USB input current to 1500 mA (measured 1160 mA)
Sep 24 10:26:08 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleARMPMUCharger: limiting USB input current to 1400 mA (measured 1141 mA)
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [Download]: Download task did finish: 7 for download: -7184518095014445338
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Installing download: -7184518095014445338 with step(s): Install
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: bundleVersion: 5106 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-7184518095014445338/2540926088173953799
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Bundle validated for bundleIdentifier: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx success: 1
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e06bf60> com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E91022C-B4DB-42E2-9BC5-50683613AA1E/-7184518095014445338.app>
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14e06bf60> com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E91022C-B4DB-42E2-9BC5-50683613AA1E/-7184518095014445338.app> withPhase:1
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x14dd52860> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5800 / Completed: 58 of 100   to 1
Sep 24 10:26:17 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-7184518095014445338/2540926088173953799" type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 103)
Sep 24 10:26:20 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Version=5106, ShortVersion=4.0>
Sep 24 10:26:20 iPad installd[46] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Sep 24 10:26:20 iPad profiled[132] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Sep 24 10:26:20 iPad profiled[132] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad online-auth-agent[313] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.xxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxx is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CCFF5229-5605-474A-8C2C-5DFA0CA7570C
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/552B30AE-9DD1-4125-8262-3C4A85F2A174
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 2.71s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.02s, Verifying: 9.36s; Overall: 12.21s
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x14e083bd0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 100 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.xxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxx
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Install complete for download: -7184518095014445338 result: Success
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Updating placeholder for download: -7184518095014445338 bundleIdentifier: com.xxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.xxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxx.Loading - <NSProgress: 0x14e0bdb30> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1 of 1   called, removing progress from cache
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad lsd[80] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, it may have been removed
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad itunesstored[103] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Placeholder updated for download: -7184518095014445338 bundleIdentifier: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx success: 1
Sep 24 10:26:29 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Installed apps did change.
    Added: {(
        "com.xxxxxxxxxxx.enterprise.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    )}
    Removed: {(
    )}
    Modified: {(
    )}
Sep 24 10:26:31 iPad lockdownd[66] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
Sep 24 10:26:31 iPad lockdownd[66] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog
Sep 24 10:26:31 iPad mobile_assertion_agent[145] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
Sep 24 10:26:37 iPad SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
```

Comment: Did you migrate to Xcode7 a.e. Swift 2?

Comment: Yes, I am using Xcode 7 and Swift 2 syntax

Comment: This is telling you that iOS tried to start up your app, but your app did not respond. After 20 seconds, iOS gave up. Something in your app is blocking execution on launch, but you'll need to look at the source code to find out what.

Comment: If something in my source code blocks the app, how to explain that the version signed by adhoc certificate works well on iOS9 on iPad ?

Comment: I don't know. You could argue that it should work or you could try debugging the app in Xcode and see what's going on.

Comment: I have debugged in XCode on the same iPad under iOS9, it works well because I am not using the inHouse certificate for the debugging. Moreover, there is no problem if I run the application on Simulator.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved this by wiping out the provisioning profiles on my device.
Go to your Xocde -> Devices -> Gear icon -> Show provisioning profiles and remove them one by one, until you remove all of them.

I don't know what iOS 9 does with Enterprise signed app, but it seems that it attempts to verify something (by going through all of your provisioning profiles) and failed a lot upon first launch. This shouldn't happen with App Store builds.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. In my case, I have used this device for development for a long time. So, a huge number(500+) of Ad-hoc, development, in-house provisioning profiles are installed(synchronised) on this device. Unfortunately, I cannot remove them in bulk, but only one by one. Eventually, I created a Automator workflow to finish the removing in some hours : )

Comment: Wow. App now runs much faster. I removed hundred profiles by hand - clicking one by one without waiting for complete and pressing backspace. The process takes some minutes)

Comment: Yep! It took me 2 days to trying different things to get my app to launch properly! Glad that it helps!

Comment: You can use Apple Configurator to remove it faster

Comment: Lifesaver, @shinichi ! I was going crazy over this :P

Comment: In xCode 9 you right-click or ctrl-click on the device in the list to access the provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @shinichi is correct. However, I needed to delete ALL enterprise provisioning profiles and do a hard reset of the device. After that there were no problems.

NOTE: If you have many EP profiles, you can delete them faster by pressing the UP button on your keyboard and positioning your mouse on the "-" button in Xcode and clicked and pressing. I know this is a stupid solution, but I had about 100 EP profiles, deleting them by clicking with the mouse would have driven me crazy.

Hope Apple fixes this.

Comment: Sorry. It says I downvoted on march 8 2016. I didn't mean to... And I can't undo it because it has been too long. :(

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7: Xcode - >devices -> ctrl+click your device -> Show provisioning profiles.

Comment: If this is an answer, it doesn't sound like a very high quality answer. Please try to make answers valuable to the community with an explanation of the answer as well as the solution, at least in cases where the explanation isn't obvious from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the provisioning profiles as suggested by the accepted answer but there were none!

My app worked for a couple hours and then all of a sudden stopped working with the same issue as described in the question.

**The solution** was to open Keychain Access and search for certificates with my developer name - sure enough, there was an old one that had expired and for some reason it was getting picked up for signing. After I deleted that expired certificate and restarted my dev environment the app started working once again.