# Titanium ios app with 5.2.0 sdk crashes at launch in run or distrib mode but works fine in debug or simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The device is iPhone 6s Plus with iOS 9.2. Using Titanium Studio, when I run in debug mode and stepping through code, the app runs fine. However, when I simply "run" it (device connected to laptop via USB) or install the .ipa file in adhoc distribution, the app crashes as soon as it is launched. There is absolutely no log generated in Titanium when "run". And there is little to no relevant information in Xcode too when the installed .ipa is run. Here is the log from Xcode:

```
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus SpringBoard[58] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus SpringBoard[58] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus securityd[96] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus securityd[96] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[311] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A3B415C-2259-A7NA-8XXD-8X5XFXCAJBDK (sandbox)
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus MySampleApp[311] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Reading stylesheet from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/H3POBLF9-PB0N-1KF5-4RXY-EEDRD90GC79X/MySampleApp.app/stylesheet.plist
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus iap2d[176] <Warning>: process com.mysampleco.mysampleapp is now running the foreground
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus UserEventAgent[26] <Warning>: Tracking com.mysampleco.mysampleapp (via activity)
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus MySampleApp[311] <Warning>: [INFO] MySampleApp/1.0.1 (5.2.0.384775e)
Mar 18 09:42:51 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus MySampleApp[311] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Loading: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/H3POBLF9-PB0N-1KF5-4RXY-EEDRD90GC79X/MySampleApp.app/app.js, Resource: app_js
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: MySampleApp(311) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.proc.all.0
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: MySampleApp(311) deny(1) process-info-pidinfo 0
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: MySampleApp(311) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.0
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus mediaserverd[28] <Notice>: '' com.mysampleco.mysampleapp(pid = 311) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus mediaserverd[28] <Notice>: 'FigPlayer - 34' (pid = 34) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.mysampleco.mysampleapp[0x72dd][311]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mysampleco.mysampleapp[0x72dd]' exited voluntarily.
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus iap2d[176] <Warning>: process com.mysampleco.mysampleapp is now switching to other state
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus iap2d[176] <Warning>: process com.mysampleco.mysampleapp is now terminated
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus UserEventAgent[26] <Warning>: 85324450686: id=com.mysampleco.mysampleapp pid=311, state=0
Mar 18 09:42:52 ThisUser-iPhone-6s-Plus SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
```

I've searched through other posts, some of whom point to "Javascript Minification" (which I turned off but still got the crash) and some talk about "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]" for Release in Code Generation section of Xcode's Build setting (which I don't know how to control since I'm using Appcelerator Titanium to build the app). Several others discuss specific code issues as revealed by the log. Since I get nothing in the log files that I can tell of significance, I'm not sure where to look.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE on March 21, 2016:
It took me a while to figure out the culprit. Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:
1) In Titanium Studio, create a new Mobile App project using Alloy Default template.
2) Run the newly created project as-is to a USB attached iPhone 6s Plus (or probably ANY ios device).
3) Click on the app icon on the device and the app will launch just fine with Hello World on the screen.
4) Now go to the TiApp.xml file and edit it by adding the following parameter:
`<property name="appc-sourcecode-encryption-policy">embed</property>`
5) Now run the modified project to the USB attached device.
6) Open the app and you will notice that it crashes right after the splash screen shows briefly.
It seems the property above does not work properly. Opened JIRA ticket [AC-3389](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3389/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a provisioning issue. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747961/enterprise-in-house-swift-application-quits-on-launch-on-ios9) which deals with a similar error.

If that does not help, please provide some more details like sample code and detailed crash logs (full trace-log). Thanks!